# ngAnchorScroll not scrolling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use the directive ngSmoothScroll to scroll to a particular element in a webpage. You can find the directive here: https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSmoothScroll

I have included the .js file in my page and included the "smoothScroll" module as a dependency in my app and controller.

There are two ways to use directive, either in the HTML as a directive like so:

```
<div scroll-to="lookAtMe">click here - scroll using directive</div>
```

Or using the functionality in javascript from a ng-click, say, like here:

```
var element = document.getElementById('lookAtMe');

var options = {
  duration: 700,
  easing: 'easeInQuad',
  callbackBefore: function(element) {
    console.log('about to scroll to element', element);
  },
  callbackAfter: function(element) {
    console.log('scrolled to element', element);
  }
}

smoothScroll(element, options);
```

Both of these should scroll to an element with id = "lookAtMe".

However, neither of these is actually scrolling. I can see in the console that the service has loaded correctly, because the callbackBefore and callbackBefore functions are printing out.

I've created a plnkr to show how exactly it is not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/LEGtF7RZWqClBHdKyuIm

And ideas why it is loading but not actually doing the scrolling? Am I missing something very obvious? All help greatly appreciated....

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: Hi - have to try it yet - working on some other stuff at the moment. Will get back to you and vote up if ti does. Thanks tasseKATT

Comment: Any updates on this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is an issue with the minified version of the script.

You can read about it [here](https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSmoothScroll/issues/57).

If you use the uncompressed version of the script it works fine:

```
<script src="angular-smooth-scroll.js"></script>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Ogp6xSL4gc2QupdliI05?p=preview